# How to correct the error message-No database selected

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql. I have one database called first.db in c:\mysql. In dos prompt I switched to c:\mysql. In mysql prompt I issued `select * from firstable;` I get the error message-No database selected. How to solve it. Thanks in advance.(firstable is a table in first.db).

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell MySQL which database to use :

```
USE database_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the active database by this command.

```
Use nameofdatabase;
```

Or modify your query to

```
SELECT * FROM nameofdatabase.table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use DatabaseName

Select * From TableName
```